# How to update entities in the DbContext without knowing their exact Type?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, dbcontext

I have an

```
object elementToUpdate;
```

and i want to update it in my DbContext.

This seems to be a good starting point

```
public void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
{
    DbContext.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
    DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296751/how-to-update-entities-which-are-modified-outside-the-dbcontext)

My problem is, that i cannot cast my `elementToUpdate` properly. I know the name of it's precise type as string (e.g. `"MyEntityType"`) but i don't know how to cast it using reflection - or in other words how to insert the Type-Parameter

```
DbContext.Set<MyEntityType>()
```

from the string

```
"MyEntityType"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you have MyEntityType in your code.if u have you can use factory pattern.

Comment: Do you really need to cast it, or do you just not know the type at compile time? If you just call `Update(elementToUpdate)` (without specifying the `<TEntity>`, it should automatically pick the right generic type for your template based on the parameter.

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh, if the entity boxed with `object` then the method would  called by `TEntity` equal to `object` not the desired type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always can use non-generic version of `DbContext.Set`:

`DbContext.Set(ObjectContext.GetObjectType(entity.GetType()))`

You can't use just `entity.GetType()` because it can be a proxy. That's why `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext` needed.

Comment: I love stack overflow and i love you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use other `Set` overload, which is not generic and accepts the type of entity as input, assuming you have the **assembly qualified name** of the object  type(if the type is in the currently executing assembly, **type name qualified by its namespace** is sufficient ):

```
public void Update(object entity, string typeName)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    DbContext.Set(type).Attach(entity);
    DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```