# Compare complex object and get difference C# .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, compare

I have two object of the class `Profile` and I want to compare it to get the difference. To explain better:

```
    public partial class Profile
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long VisitorId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public long Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set;}
    }
```

I want to know in my method the differences between the object `oldProfile` and `newProfile` to make a changelog.

For example, if `oldProfile` had `Age = 10` and `Description = "old"` and `newProfile` has `Age = 11` and `Description = "new"`, I would now this differences to make two different insert in my database:

```
public void PostChangelogProfileDetail(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile)
{
    ProfileDetailChangeLog profileDetailChangeLog = new ProfileDetailChangeLog();

    //COMPARE oldProfile AND newProfile

    foreach ( //difference resulted in the compare)
    {
        profileDetailChangeLog.VisitorId = newProfile.VisitorId;
        profileDetailChangeLog.ModifiedRecord = //name of the attribute modified (Age, Description, etc...)

        _profileDetailChangeLog.Create(profileDetailChangeLog);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are various ways to compare object 1) write your code to compare property by property 2) use a library; for example you can use Json to find the difference using jsondiffpatch.net. Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876082/find-and-return-json-differences-using-newtonsoft-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install package from nugget
Install-Package ObjectsComparer

And then imply compare : 
var cmpr = new Comparer();
/* compare 
isSame  is the booleab variable and will return true if both objects are same
  */ 
IEnumerable diff;

bool isSame = cmpr.Compare(obj1, obj2, out diff);

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see this package and it's perfect for my needs. It's also free to use right?

Comment: Really liked the framework but it's a bit redundant if you want to update your database anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely looking to use EF Cores Metadata about an object it is tracking to determine the changes to it. I have done something similar to the stackoverflow solution myself in .net core 3 which makes me believe 3.1 should work as well.

There are articles describing approaches for this in the following articles:
[Getting all changes made to an object in the Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265257/getting-all-changes-made-to-an-object-in-the-entity-framework) & [ChangeTracker in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/changetracker-in-ef-core.aspx).

Comment: Didn't know this thing, I will for sure consider in future this kind of approach.

Answer (score 2):

When you call [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.add?view=efcore-3.1) or [Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContext_Update__1___0_) ef core returns [EntityEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry?view=efcore-3.1).
From which `EntityEntry` you can get the current and old values via the `OriginalValues`(returns the old values) and the `CurrentValues`(returns the new values) properties.

From where you can compare and log the differences from the original and the current values via Reflection to see the type/name of the property and the value as their return type is [PropertyValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.propertyvalues?view=efcore-3.1) .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will keep in mind this tip.

Comment: See my answer on how you don't have to query the CurrentValues yourselves.

Answer (score 1):

For disconnected entities, I found this [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities).

For finding changes on an existing entity:

```
var existing = context.Find<Item>(1);
if (existing != null) 
{ 
   context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(changed);
}
```

Its EntityState will be `Modified` afterwards but only where there are actual changes.

Had the same answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65687458/129269).